# Displaying records in a nice layout

Tags: asp.net, html, css, sql-server-2008

I have a database where I want to display 2 records in a nicely formatted ASP.NET with HTML

Each record would look like this on the web page

[image]

The layout would be layers.  The data is in a SQL Server 2008 r2 database.

Now whats the best way to get data to populate each record.

Repeater?  Or another method?

Regards
Tea

Comment: What have you tried? People on SO tend to be more helpful to people who actually have put effort in trying and searching before asking. After all, that's how people learn.

Comment: If you have only two records, you don't need to use repeater. And also repeater is not a `method` its a control !!!

Comment: There are 2 records at the moment, there could be more added later on in the database.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: How is your format going to be? is it will be same for each record?

Comment: The look is what I've already shown above.  Yes same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeater control is an easy control to use to make sure that your data is displayed the same for all entries in a given data source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

Comment: Can you only use table, tr, td, with a Repeater?  I want to use div layers to format my layout.

Comment: The Repeater will repeat with whatever code you place in the <itemtemplate>. So if these are divs or table layouts. Its just that most people use them with tables if they ues them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a template and will follow the same html for each entries so it would be better to go for repeater as you will have more control over the html,css and the placemnet part.

Answer (score 0):

yes repeater is best option to use in this situation or you can generate the whole html on you code behind page and assign it to a literal control.